# How ReactJs component could retrieve var from componentWillMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var React = require('react');

var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
componentWillMount: function() {
    someVariable = "Variable";
    return someVariable
},
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>{someVariable}</div>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = SomeComponent;
```

how component could retrive someVariable from componentWillMount?

Comment: i guess you can simply use `this.someVariable`, `componentWillMount` executes once before the first render.

Answer (score 5):

Your example works because you're defining a *global* variable that the `render` method then can access. This is typically bad.
What I think you're really after is setting this variable on the initial state of your component.

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function () {
      return {someVariable: 'Variable'};
   },
   render: function () {
      return <div>{this.state.someVariable}</div>
   }
});
```

Setting state with `this.setState` within `componentWillMount` is fine as well but will override any initial state your component has since the render will still only execute once therefore it makes more sense to do it within `getInitialState` if it's something that's supposed to be local to the component.

Answer (score 2):

The typical pattern is to use state via `setState`. But if you have something you need to set, the best thing is to pass it in as a property. Another option is to add a `getInitialState` (although the [documentation suggests this is an anti-pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)).

If you want to do it in `componentWillMount`, I would try this:

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    var someVariable = "Variable";
    this.setState({someVariable: someVariable});
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.state.someVariable}</div>;
  }
});
```

It will work but it'll likely generate a warning about using `setState` in a lifecycle event and it's a bad practice (I'd prefer to use `getInitialState` over `componentWillMount` for this specific instance).